# Switch Red and Blue channels of Video file in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Suppose I have a video file and I want to swap the red and blue channels of the video file. How can I do this with ffmpeg?

Comment: I'd try the [shuffleplanes](https://libav.org/documentation/libavfilter.html#shuffleplanes) video filter, but I haven't actually done this myself.

Comment: Is the video YUV or RGB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

variant 1: [colorchannelmixer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorchannelmixer)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v colorchannelmixer=0:0:1:0:0:1:0:0:1:0:0 output.mkv
```

rgb, group for 4 digits separated with colon `0:0:1:0` - rgba format